# What is the maximum character length limit of Char field with no specified size?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

What is the default maximum character size limit of Char field with no specified size?

The field is created like this.

```
name = fields.Char(string='Name')
```

*Odoo version 14, Community Edition*

Comment: IIRC it's limited by the database so you have to look up `varchar` max size for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo will use the [pg_varchar](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/fields.py#L1629) function to return the `VARCHAR` declaration for the provided size. If no size (or an empty or negative size) is provided, it will return an `infinite VARCHAR` otherwise return a `VARCHAR(n)`

Odoo will not set the maximum size and the longest possible character string that can be stored in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) is about `1GB`